# Create new Powershell Variable with Values from replace

Tags: powershell

I need some help with an Powershell Script which reads specify lines from an textfile and create an new variable with values from the txtfile. The Variablename should be the $var1 and the value should be $var2.

The Value from the new created variable should be something like this

```
$number = 4
$Computername = "Test123$number"
```

```
$txt = Get-Content -Path .xyz.txt | Where-Object {$_ -like '@set*'}

foreach ($line in $txt){
    $firstclip=$line.IndexOf("(")
    $delimiter=$line.IndexOf(",")
    $lastclip=$line.IndexOf(")")

    $var1=$line.Substring($firstclip+1,$delimiter - ($firstclip + 1))
    $var2=$line.Substring($delimiter+1,$lastclip - ($delimiter + 1))
    $var2=$var2 -replace '%([^-]+)%','$$$1'

    Write-Host $var1
    Write-host $var2

    #New-Variable -Name $var1 -Value $var2
}
```

Content of TXT File `.xyz.txt`:

```
@Set(DeviceID, 11)
@Set(ComputerName, PC-Name-%DeviceID%)

@Set(Nic0Name, LAN)
@Set(Nic0Ip, 10.42.50.101)
@Set(Nic0Mask, 255.255.255.0)
@Set(Nic0Gateway, 10.42.50.50)

@Set(AmsNetId, %Nic0Ip%.1.1)

@Set(AmsRoute0Name, PC-NAME-01)
@Set(AmsRoute0Ip, 10.42.50.51)
@Set(AmsRoute0AmsNetId, %AmsRoute0Ip%.1.1)

@Set(VAS, 10.42.50.42)
@Set(IEHomePage, http://%VAS%/web/PC-0%DeviceID%.html)

@Set(IEPath, "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe")
```

Actually the Value is Test123$number, so Powershell wouldnt convert the $number in the number declared in an variable before.

Comment: This is a poor technique for dealing with variables.  You should consider using an array or a hashtable instead.  If you really want to use this method, then you should post some example content from the text file so people can see what your code is dealing with.

Comment: please add the content of one of the files you are working with to your Original Post.

Comment: thank you for adding the TXT file info. [*grin*] now, how do you get the `%SomeNameHere%` info into PoSh -- or do you want to leave that unchanged?

Comment: that is exactly my problem. I want to changed the values in the textfile with %SomeNameHere% with an value from the new created variable instead. So the variable computername should habe the value PC-Name-$DeviceID. If I check the value from $deviceid it works fine. But if I set the Value for $computername then it will return me PC-Name-$DeviceID instead PC-NAME-11

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `-split` operator with an alternate to process input lines,
and check with an `if` and a RegEx if there are %var% to replace with current $var content.

**EDIT: to better visualize changes, output a `[PSCustomObject]`**
**EDIT2: needed to switch to Select-String with -AllMatches**

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\20\SO_56218447.ps1

$txt = Get-Content -Path .xyz.txt | Where-Object {$_ -like '@set*'}
$RE = '%([^%]+)%'

foreach ($line in $txt){
    $Name,$Value = ($line -split '\(|\)|, ')[1,2]
    $NewValue = $Value
    ($Value)|Select-String -Pattern $RE -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches}|ForEach-Object{
        $NewValue = $NewValue -replace $_.value,(Get-Variable -Name $_.value.Trim('%')).Value
    }
    New-Variable -Name $Name -Value $NewValue
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Variable = $Name
        Value    = $Value
        NewValue = $NewValue
    }
}
```

Sample output

```
> Q:\Test\2019\05\20\SO_56218447.ps1

Variable          Value                                             NewValue
--------          -----                                             --------
DeviceID          11                                                11
ComputerName      PC-Name-%DeviceID%                                PC-Name-11
Nic0Name          LAN                                               LAN
Nic0Ip            10.42.50.101                                      10.42.50.101
Nic0Mask          255.255.255.0                                     255.255.255.0
Nic0Gateway       10.42.50.50                                       10.42.50.50
AmsNetId          %Nic0Ip%.1.1                                      10.42.50.101.1.1
AmsRoute0Name     PC-NAME-01                                        PC-NAME-01
AmsRoute0Ip       10.42.50.51                                       10.42.50.51
AmsRoute0AmsNetId %AmsRoute0Ip%.1.1                                 10.42.50.51.1.1
VAS               10.42.50.42                                       10.42.50.42
IEHomePage        http://%VAS%/web/PC-0%DeviceID%.html              http://10.42.50.42/web/PC-011.html
IEPath            "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks thats the perfect solution!

Comment: I just discovered a flaw with multiple %var% in one value, I've to think abozt it.

Comment: The Solution with CustomObjects is very nice, but why %DeviceID% will be changed to %VAS%? Normally the IEHomePage should look like http://$Vas/dftweb/induction-0$deviceID.html